# Cannot access apache from lan computer when server has static IP

Tags: networking, apache2, dhcp

I started with a fresh build of 20.04 with static IP. Updates done. No firewall enabled. Apache2 installed. I cannot access the apache site from a remote computer on the lan, only the server, either by localhost or the IP.

Now I've got a fresh build of 20.04 with DHCP IP. Updates done. No firewall enabled. Apache2 installed. I *CAN* access the apache site from a remote computer on the lan.

I change the netplan to static.  I can't access apache site from remote computer.  I change the netplan to DHCP.  I *CAN* access apache site from remote computer. etc, etc, etc, ad infinitum.

Can anyone explain this?

my (static) netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.55/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [209.18.47.63,209.18.47.61]
```

From what I've been able to tell from the logs, when it's not working, the server gets a request from the client, and is returning a 200 OK code, but is not getting an acknowledgement from the client.  The client does not get the 200 OK code.

Comment: What's your Apache's VirtualHost configuration? More importantly, do you have a `<VirtualHost addr:port>` directive or a `Listen` directive in the config that specify a specific IP?

Comment: Does your machine have more than one network device, such as `enp0s25` and `wlp3s0`? If so, the device that is to receive the static IP needs to be listed right under the `ethernets:` line, followed by a colon. Alternatively, when I configure static IPs manually, I generally use `dhcp4: no` rather than `false` ... but I believe both options are valid.

Comment: @Matigo: sorry, this was just a typo on my part: the interface 'eth0' is listed in my actual .yaml file under ethernets:.  I just have that one network device.  I have tried with dhcp 'no' and 'false' as well as just omitting a line with dhcp -- all have the same effect.

Comment: @Dan: thanks for the edit clarifying my netplan.  No modifications to the website, just straight from the .iso build, so between the VirtualHost xml tags is just ServerAdmin DocumentRoot ErrorLog and CustomLog properties in the 000-default.conf file. The ports.conf file has just 'Listen 80' and a couple of 'Listen 443' properties under IfModule constraints.